# Spark Java error NoClassDefFoundError on Amazon Elastic MapReduce

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-spark, emr

I am trying to implement and run a Spark application on Amazon's Elastic MapReduce (EMR). So far I have been able to deploy and run a cluster with a "Spark Installation" bootstrap action using the following link:

> s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/spark/0.8.1/install-spark-shark.sh

The script can be accessed from [this](http://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/spark/0.8.1/install-spark-shark.sh) internet direction.

In order to upload the .jar application to the cluster, I have created a step configuration as follows:

```
 HadoopJarStepConfig customConfig = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                 .withJar("s3://mybucket/SparkApp.jar")
                 .withMainClass("SparkApp.java");

 StepConfig customJarStep = new StepConfig()
                 .withName("Run custom jar")                                                                                    
                 .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.CONTINUE)
                 .withHadoopJarStep(customConfig);
```

Finally, the following code shows the actual Spark application extracted from the wordcount example provided by the Spark team (For the 0.8.1 version). As you may notice, the code imports different spark libraries to be able to run the application. The libraries are:

> spark-core_2.9.3-0.8.1-incubating.jar
>    (and) 
>   scala-library-2.9.3.jar

```
import scala.Tuple2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SparkApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext("local", "JavaWordCount",
        System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), System.getenv("SPARK_EXAMPLES_JAR"));
    JavaRDD<String> lines = ctx.textFile("c3://murquiabucket/wordcount.txt", 1);

    JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
      public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
        return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
      }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = words.map(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
      public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
      }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = ones.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
      public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        return i1 + i2;
      }
    });

    List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> output = counts.collect();
    for (Tuple2 tuple : output) {
      System.out.println(tuple._1 + ": " + tuple._2);
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to execute the jar (I made a fat jar to embed the necessary libraries) in the EMR cluster. The application terminates unsuccessfully due to the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/mesos/Scheduler    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ...

For what I understand, there is a issue with Mesos, which I am not able to understand. If this information helps, this is the information of the EMR cluster:

- AMI Version: 2.4.2
- Hadoop Distribution: Amazon 1.0.3
- Spark Version: 0.8.1
- Scala Version: 2.9.3

Comment: So you tried to build a fat jar? and it still didn't work? My suspicion is the version of Spark you have imported is different from what is on the cluster. What version of Spark are you importing?

Comment: @samthebest I have checked the bootstrap file provided by Amazon at [link](https://elasticmapreduce.s3.amazonaws.com/samples/spark/install-spark-shark.sh) and it seems that the Spark version is 0.5, while my application is developed using the 1.0 version. I will check if it works now.

Comment: Wow 0.5 that's from the stone age.  Last time I checked I thought they where on 0.8.1 (more like bronze age).

Comment: @samthebest Yes, I now switched to the 0.8.1 version :P. I made a fat jar again but a different NoClassDefFoundError appears, this time refering to the mesos scheduler. I have updated the question to fit this new situation.

Comment: Please include all the coordinates of the maven artefacts your pulling in.

Comment: I wasn't using Maven. However, the error was in fact due to the mismatched versions of Spark on EMR and my application. I will create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @samthebest on the comments above, the error was in fact due to a mismatched error of the Spark version on EMR and my application.

What I learned from this error is that it is very important to check that all the libraries and applications used in the execution of a custom application use the same versions as the cluster.

Comment: Tip: Don't use EMR!! We use EC2 and stick to the Cloudera packages to install spark and the cloudera maven coords for our jars.

Comment: Indeed. I had too many complications setting up a Spark EMR infrastructure, so I switched to Spark Standalone and now I am running my own complex application pretty quickly. Thanks for the tip!